# Can't remove Gatsby NPM package on MacOS

Tags: macos, npm, package, gatsby

I'm having some issues getting Gatsby working. I want to remove my previous installation and start fresh.

Running `npm list -g --depth 0` reveals:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── gatsby-cli@2.12.68
├── grunt-cli@1.3.2
└── npm@6.4.1
```

When I run `npm uninstall --save -g gatsby-cli@2.12.68` the output is `up to date in 0.031s` - yet the Gatsby NPM package is still there.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Try removing it with just ```npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli```

Comment: You could also manually purge the appropriate folder from the global node_modules if you have to.

Comment: Great thanks @Mark - that was the solution. Thank you :)